# Open flash camera settings from action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, video-capture

I have to do a flash app using camera capture on a touchscreen with right click disabled.

Is there a way to open the flash camera settings dialog from actionscript?
Or even better the whole right click menu.

So I may open it from a self made maintenance button or so.
I know it will display automatically if the user never selected a camera, but I want to change cameras from time to time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bring up the panel by doing this:

```
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.system.SecurityPanel;

Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
```